# Updating O365 Group logo using Graph api with application permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update O365 Group logo using Microsoft Graph API with Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library and `GraphServiceClient`.

Created app and added `Group.ReadWrite.All` (Admin Only) permissions to Application, did Admin consent to app.

When setting logo to Group I'll get exception `Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.`

Is there some other permissions that I need to add or is there some limitations to update logo using app permissions?

Here's the line of code that throws exception:

```cs
await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Photo.Content.Request().PutAsync(file.ContentStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a Group's photo isn't supported using Application permissions. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#groups-and-microsoft-teams):

> Examples of group features that support only delegated permissions:
>
> - Group conversations, events, photo
> - External senders, accepted or rejected senders, group subscription
> - User favorites and unseen count
> - Microsoft Teams channels and chats.

Comment: Link yields 404. New link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#groups